# Static linking of linux audio libraries

Tags: linux, linker, alsa, pulseaudio, jack

I'm working on an audio library that's targeting both Windows and Linux. For the Windows backends I support DirectSound, WASAPI and ASIO, and for Linux it's ALSA, JACK and PulseAudio. Recently the topic of static vs. shared/dynamic linking of the c/c++ runtime (msvcrt/libc/libgcc/libstdc++) and additional dependencies came up, in light of being self-contained and library-version-independent. I decided to settle on static linking everything (DirectSound, WASAPI, ASIO and msvcrt) for Windows, because DirectSound and WASAPI are built-in, and I compile ASIO from source. But for Linux things seem a bit more complicated. This here: https://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2012/07/creating-portable-linux-binaries.html suggests I'm reasonably safe by static linking libgcc and libstdc++, but not libc itself (correct me if I'm wrong). But i have absolutely no clue about what to do with libasound, libpulse, and libjack-jackd2. APT packages even seem to provide only .so's, not .a's.

So my question basically boils down to this: how do I produce a shared library (.so) on linux, using all of libc, libgcc, libstdc++, libasound, libjack, and libpulse, while being as much self-contained as possible, require end-users to install as little as possible, and run on a as wide variety of linux distros as possible (not interested in other *NIXes).

If it makes any difference, the main goal (for now) is to publish wrapper libraries around this native binary both for .NET on nuget.org and Java on Maven central. I just want a consumer of the package to be able to say "packagereference include=audiolib" and be done with it, then be able to run on a wide range of platforms.

Really appreciate if someone from the ALSA/Pulse/JACK team can shed some light on this as there's at least some material out there on static linking GCC's runtimes, but next to nothing on the specific audio libs.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I finally gave up :). See here https://github.com/sjoerdvankreel/xt-audio/issues/8 for some background info if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick google search and here's what I gathered:

- **ALSA** [officially supports static linking](https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-lib/blob/master/INSTALL#L47), and you can very easily build the static library yourself if your distro doesn't provide it.
- **PulseAudio** [apparently can be statically linked](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1089#note_751107) but I couldn't find any resources explaining further.
- **JACK** cannot be linked statically, however [there's a workaround](https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/issues/743#issuecomment-820808551).

Comment: I was able to build `alsa-lib` with `--enable-static`, and statically link the final program, but then alsa tried to load plugins (`lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_ctl_pulse.so`) dynamically, which defeats the purpuose